# Blender hangs when I parent with automatic weights (file given)

Tags: rigging, bones, parent

I am an absolute beginner. I have been following a rigging tutorial after modeling a character called Berk by Grant Abbitt. I have removed subdivision surface and mirror modifiers and applied all transformations to my model. The moment I select "Parent->with automatic weights", Blender hangs up. I have used different versions of blender and different PC's to check but all hang up. This is the tutorial that ive been following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=El7xmgNyPPo.

Also, here is a link to my file: https://tinyurl.com/4asan7yp

Any tips to resolve the issue will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow! I'm a little confused, I can't understand, how you have been able to produce this file:

[image]

There are 3 armatures, and none of them containing bones. Looks like the file is broken somehow, so let's fix that.

First, go to the Object data tab and get the name of our armature. It's looks like it is called "Armature":

[image]

Next, let's delete our broken object, that's not displayed in the Outliner. Select them and delete

[image]

Next, select one of the empty armatures, for example, Armature.001:

[image]

And in object data tab select "Armature" from the list. It should be with a 0 icon, because we have deleted its object.

[image]

That is it. Now armature works as expected.

Comment: I'm new. As you can see doing a VERY basic tutorial. Thus, THANK YOU for such a clear and elaborate explanation and bothering to break it down for someone like me. You are a HERO!